# Bootstrap modal only shows after function completes, but not when I call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm creating a HTML5 tool for something at my work.

My goal is: 
Click the Go! button. Show the modal. Start the process of getting the lat long for all entered locations by starting the each loop and get the locations lat/lon via the ajax requests and closing the modal when these are all done.

The modal can be shown by using the button TEST and it can also be shows after the function finishes but not when it starts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {



$('#pleaseWaitDialog').click(function () {
        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
    });


    $('#csvImportBtn').click(function () {
        $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('show');
        var csvText = $('#csvUpload').val();
        var data = csvUpload(csvText);
        $('#status').html('Getting lat long for: ' + data.length + 'devices...');
        getLatLon(data);


    });


});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VeldMuijz/10q7aqam/7/) is the fiddle of the complete page, it doesn't seem to work for me from jsfiddle, but I can run it in a normal HTML page without errors.

I've tested this in Chrome 'Version 38.0.2125.111 m'.

Can anyone advise how I'll be able to show it on the start of the process (after clicking Go!)? Because I'm pretty lost right now.

Edit:
Here is the testdata to be pasted in the textarea:

```
device_id,address,city
118001,Wipmolenweg 13,Almere
118002,Wipmolenweg 14,Almere
118003,Wipmolenweg 15,Almere
118004,Wipmolenweg 16,Almere
118005,Wipmolenweg 17,Almere
118006,Wipmolenweg 18,Almere
118007,Wipmolenweg 19,Almere
118008,Wipmolenweg 20,Almere
118009,Wipmolenweg 21,Almere
118010,Wipmolenweg 22,Almere
```

Edit: Still stuck.. Can anybody help? Also changed the title for a better description.

Comment: You really should try to narrow this down to the piece of code you're having a problem with. I feel there's way too much here to properly parse through, not to mention it's formatted badly for some reason.

Comment: I'll throw it in a JSFiddle when i'm home, JSFiddle refreshes the page and resets all the boxes upon saving on this machine.